# Intellisense not picking up Redux store type

Tags: visual-studio-code, redux

I'm following a tutorial on Redux and in the video the person sets up a store and goes to type `store.subscribe` and Intellisense picks up that it's a redux store and shows the `subscribe` method on it.  When I try to do this, following the exact same code, my Intellisense picks up the `store` as `any`.  Am I missing an extension or something?  I've tried a few react/redux extensions but they don't seem to pick up `store` as being redux.

Code here: https://pastebin.com/9cAbHzSR

The presenters screen:
[image]

My screen
[image]
[image]